# Alfresco activiti workflow deploy

Tags: workflow, alfresco, activiti

I have a bit of a problem.
I have created a workflow with the Activiti plugin in Eclipse.
I have a model, context file and the bpmn20.xml file.
Everything is deployed in shared/alfresco/extension but:
If I deploy the workflow deleting the entire following tag in the bpmn20.xml file

```
  <bpmndi:BPMNDiagram id="BPMNDiagram_activitiCustomWorkflow">
```

(so basically without the workflow diagram), everything works fine but I can't see the workflow diagram in the Workflow details page in Alfresco Share .
If I leave that tag (so what Eclipse created in the beginning with the Activiti project), 
Alfresco is not starting. (Connection rejected in browser)
Log is not telling me nothing, and Tomcat cannot be stopped normally (I have to delete the catalina.pid and the tomcat temp folder manually).

My bpmn20.xml file header is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <definitions xmlns="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:activiti="http://activiti.org/bpmn"
    xmlns:bpmndi="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/DI"
    xmlns:omgdc="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DC"
    xmlns:omgdi="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DI"
    typeLanguage="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    expressionLanguage="http://www.w3.org/1999/XPath"
    targetNamespace="http://activiti.org/bpmn20">
```

Am I missing something? Or maybe Eclipse doesn't create the correct bpmn file? 
Ah, Alfresco 4.0.d and Ubuntu server 10.04 LTS x64
I am using Activiti engine, and the jBPM engine is turned off.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: which log are you looking in? catalina.out or alfresco.log? Do you need to turn your logging up to debug in log4j.properties?

Comment: I've looked in both logs, I have already enabled debug for workflows,
catalina.out is everything ok, last log is server startup in nnnn milliseconds, and there are no errors.
alfresco.log is the same, no errors, but it arrives at some point (after the jetty 7070 ok line), it stops sending log messages. And it seems to remain appended there.
Nothing happens, and I have tomcat/alfresco/share rejected connection message if I try to reach them from a browser.

Answer (score 2):

You might need to turn up the logging in webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties.

```
log4j.logger.org.alfresco.repo.workflow=debug
```

I've also got that set in webapps/share/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties

Comment: sorry, forgot to mention, I've already enabled debug in log4. Still nothing.
I found out, if I deploy the workflow without the bpmndi:BPMNDiagram tag (so the graphical layout), the workflow is deployed correctly.

Comment: I've had problems with Activiti Designer where I've renamed flows but the names on the diagram stayed the same. This would cause the kind of errors your mentioning but in my case I was getting messages in the logs which pointed that out (e.g. 'flow7 does not exist' where I'd renamed it 'escalationFlow' or something). It's a bit of a pain but I'd look through the bpmn diagram definition and check that all the flow names do exist in your diagram. Of course if you haven't renamed any flows that might not be relevant.

Answer (score 1):

my Eclipse (activity designer) generates header like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:activiti="http://activiti.org/bpmn" xmlns:bpmndi="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/DI" xmlns:omgdc="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DC" xmlns:omgdi="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DI" typeLanguage="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" expressionLanguage="http://www.w3.org/1999/XPath" targetNamespace="Onlio">
  <process id="OnlioWFAdhocMultiNonEsc" name="WF name/description" isExecutable="true">
```

But I've had also a problem with that, so I'm using this (and this works for me :) ), so you can try it ..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:activiti="http://activiti.org/bpmn"
xmlns:bpmndi="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/DI"
xmlns:omgdc="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DC"
xmlns:omgdi="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DI"
typeLanguage="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
expressionLanguage="http://www.w3.org/1999/XPath"
targetNamespace="http://alfresco.org">

  <process id="WFID" name="WF name/description" isExecutable="true">
```

(there's different in targetNameSpace only)

So, good luck :)

Btw for deploy you will need a context file or workflow console :) (there should be also way how to deploy through data dictionary- I'm not sure how :) )

OT btw2 - for logging I'm setting these 2 params:
*(in ..`\tomcat\webapps\alfresco\WEB-INF\classes\log4j.properties`)*

```
log4j.logger.org.alfresco.repo.jscript=debug
log4j.logger.org.alfresco.repo.jscript.ScriptLogger=debug
```